# How many episodes does season 7 of SWTCW have?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I was wondering how many episodes the new *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* season (Season 7) had? On most (if not all) websites, the contents of the first 10 episodes are teased (ending with Ahsoka facing Maul), but there isn't any content for the last two episodes (11+12)...

Is this a miscommunication error, because most (official) SW sites list 12 episodes or is the content simply not disclosed yet?

Comment: I'm torn here - on the one hand, the lack of research (such as quickly [checking Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_episodes#Season_7:_The_Final_Season_(2020))) means I can't upvote.  On the *other* hand, having watched the first 4 episodes on Disney+, there was no indication of more episodes coming (the UI of that site could be **greatly** improved), which had led me to think it was just a *very short* season with 1 multi-episode story - so, I have found the question useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are twelve episodes. They just haven't released episode descriptions or information about 11 or 12 yet.

See the announcement article [here](https://www.starwars.com/news/sdcc-2018-the-clone-wars-to-return):

> Announced by Dave Filoni at San Diego Comic-Con during a 10th anniversary celebration of the beloved animated series, Star Wars: The Clone Wars will be returning with 12 all-new episodes on Disney+.

Answer (score 0):

*Star wars: The Clone Wars* is definitely the longest running Star Wars series ever. With 7 seasons now is coming to an end.

- Season 1: 22
- Season 2: 22
- Season 3: 22
- Season 4: 22
- Season 5: 20
- Season 6: 13
- Season 7: 12

There are a total of 133 episodes in the whole series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This would be a better answer if you linked to some reasonably reliable source for the episode count instead of just giving a number.